# How can I prove that $\langle A|A\rangle$ is a real number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

I want to learn, how I can prove that $\langle A|A\rangle$ is a real number. Sorry for the simple question, but I am new in learning Quantum Mechanics and its maths.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple using $\langle A|B \rangle = \overline{\langle B|A \rangle}$ and $\mathfrak{Re}(z) = \frac12(z+\overline z)$:

\begin{equation}
\langle A|A \rangle = \frac{\langle A|A \rangle+\langle A|A \rangle}2
=\frac{\langle A|A \rangle+\overline{\langle A|A \rangle}}2
=\mathfrak{Re}(\langle A|A \rangle) \in \mathbb R
\end{equation}